# make new ajax request when previous one finished

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

i have checkboxes on html page for which JQuery `click` event is triggered which makes the ajax call. Once request is finished html page is rendered with response data.

```
fetchActivites = ()->
  $.ajax
    beforeSend: ()->
      $('#checkbox_loader').show()

    url: "/project/users/"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      plotData(data, is_append)
    complete: ()->
      $('#checkbox_loader').hide()
```

Issue is, while one ajax request is going on. user can `click` another check box and another ajax request is made, before first one getting completed. which is messing up the data to be rendered.

```
$(document).on "change", ".selectpicker", (evt) ->
  fetchActivites()
```

using `async: false`, seems bad practice, have its own drawbacks.

Is there any other way to accomplish the task ?

Comment: Will plain old javascript answer be fine? :)

Comment: not sure, but please do

Comment: Well, if you are not sure about javascript I wouldn't waste your time. Let's wait for coffeescripter.

Comment: you could use the one jquery function and reset it in the complete callback. or you could disable the checkboxes until the request is complete. or you could put some sort of overlay/spinnerimage over the checkboxes showing the progress until its done.

Answer (score 0):

Since noone has come around here is a javascript solution.

```
var pending; //current request
function enqueueFetchActivities(/*args*/) {
    var current,
        ctx = this,  //save current context
        args = [].slice.call(arguments), //and arguments
        doFetch = function() { //transparent invoker;
            return fetchActivities.apply(ctx, args);
        };
    pending = current = 
          pending ? pending.then(doFetch) : doFetch();

    return current.always(function() { //always try to remove pending 
        if(pending === current) { //otherwise another request was made
             pending = null;
        }
    });       
}
function fetchActivites() {
    return $.ajax(/*...*/);//whatever you want it to do.
}
```

Now you can call `enqueueFetchActivities` the way you was calling `fetchActivites` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
# if another ajax request comes when the previous request has not finished,
# just abort the previous one.
promise?.abort()
promise = $.ajax
  # some ajax params
promise.success = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
  plotData(data, is_append)
promise.complete = ()->
  $('#checkbox_loader').hide()
```